# DEST value defined in localrc

Tags: openstack, devstack

If we specifically mention DEST=/opt/stack/new in localrc, does that mean this will be used throughout the code base like this variable is used in stack.sh file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `DEST=/opt/stack/new` in the localrc file. means you have store a variable in the file, but now it is not environment variable except you source it.

In devstack, the code will execute it when installing the openstack, so you should make sure the localrc's permission.

The localrc should under `/home/devstack`, so make sure:

```
chown -R stack:stack /home/devstack
```